# How to simulate modless window dialogs in dojo so that we can have multiple windows panes open

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dojo

In desktop applications we usually have parent window and multiple child windows. How do I simulate such behavior in the web application?

I use the dojo/dialog for modal dialogs in dojo which appears as popup and need user actions to close the dialog window to access any items in the main window.

What should I use in dojo to have multiple window panes open at the same time and user can work any of the window panes. This is something similar to Gmail's chat window. Gmail opens multiple chat window panes and still allows user to access the main gmail window.

If that is possible with dojo/ other frameworks then what about the browser compatibility.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dojox.layout.FloatingPane may what you are looking for.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/layout/FloatingPane

Comment: I saw the floating pane is available in dojo. But that is in experimental stage not suggested for production environment.

Comment: @ram  That's the only solution of dojo right now. Yes, it is still in experimental stage, but it existed for a long time and should have been used by a lots of projects. There is no serious issues.